# Opening device file and error code in linux-kernel

Tags: linux, driver, device

I am new to kernel programming and I have two questions:

1. My device is getting registered (by dynamic registration) but my
   application is not able to open the device file. What could be the
   possible reasons?
2. What would be the appropriate error code to return when my device
   driver detects an divide by zero?

My code implements simple arithmetic operations in the kernel. I use an `ioctl()` based interface to communicate between user space and the kernel.

```
if(out.b==0) /*checking for divide by zero*/
  out.res=-EINVAL;
else
  out.res=out.a/out.b;

copy_to_user((values*)ioctl_param,&out,sizeof(values));
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't possibly answer the first question if you don't show us your code.

As for the second, `EINVAL` or perhaps `ERANGE`.

In your case you need to make the distinction between the information you return in the `ioctl_param` structure (that's a *really* bad variable name by the way) and the return status of the `ioctl()` call itself.

Remember that `ioctl()` returns 0 if it completes successfully, and sets errno if it fails.
The kernel and C library take care of most of that for you. Usually all you have to do is return `-EINVAL` or similar from your `ioctl()` function.

Something like this:

```
if(out.b == 0) /*checking for divide by zero*/
  return -EINVAL;

out.res=out.a / out.b;

copy_to_user((values*)ioctl_param,&out,sizeof(values));
break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But EINVAL and ERANGE also represent numbers. Suppose my output of division is stored in a variable result. So when i a detect a division by zero, if i do result=-EINVAL , whn printing the result i will get -22 as the output. how will i differentiate between this -22 and say -44/2.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more detail on what your device does, but I'd rather strongly recommend having a status reporting channel independent of whatever data you return.

Comment: My device does basic operations of addition, subtraction multiplication and division. It takes two variables from user space and does the operations and returns back the result to user space.

Comment: Please provide some more information channel and how exactly is implemented.

Comment: What interface do you use? `ioctl()` on a char device node? `read()/write()`? A netlink socket? (Additionally, please edit your original question to add this information, or even better a minimal sample of code illustrating your problem.)

Comment: Yes I am using the IOCTL information.My driver also has read and write functions. My code for division is  if(out.b==0)/*checking for divide by zero*/
                                out.res=-EINVAL;
                        else
                                out.res=out.a/out.b;
                        copy_to_user((values*)ioctl_param,&out,sizeof(values));
                        break;

Comment: Edit the original question please. Code in comments is unreadable.